# jQuery how to move to to href div automatically?

Tags: jquery, scroll, slider

I am new to jQuery and have menus links that href to nodes of different classes. The problem is that the distance between the links and the content that they refer to is too long so the user need to scroll down a lot to reach the destination content. So I am wondering hwo to use jQuery to do that. I have read the [w3schools intro to jQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp) and tried some seemingly similar problems on SO (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16496279/517235)). but none worked and still puzzled how to write that snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#mydiv").offset().top
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mVqq3/

Comment: I have to use jQuery 1.3.2 (shipped with Drupal). Could be because of that?

Comment: Have no idea... check for errors in console. Does anything happen after click or nothing? The div offset scope may not be top one, so its .top could be relative to parent element. If so, you need to transform it to body scope by adding parents top to it.